# .gitignore_global has no effect on .idea/ created by JetBrains

Tags: gitignore, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to get Git to ignore `.idea/` created by JetBrains' product but somehow it works on every folder I created except the `.idea/` created by JetBrains. Why ?

So how do I globally ignore `.idea/` ?

I already had my `core.excludesfile` set to `~/.gitignore_global`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first that folder was not *already* tracked:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git rm -r --cached .idea/
```

Then check your `git status`: add, commit (register the deletion): the `.gitignore` should now be in effect for that folder.

To check that the folder ignore rule is in effect:

```
git check-ignore -v -- .idea/a_file_inside_.idea_folder
```

As long as it returns nothing, that file (inside the `.idea` folder) is not ignored.
That [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) command will consider *all* ignore files possible, including the `core.excludesfile` one (in your case set to `~/.gitignore_global`)

Comment: I want to ignore it in .gitignore_global, not .gitignore

Comment: @apollo The answer remains the same: whatever you are using to ignore that folder (`.gitignore_global` or `.gitignore`), as long as said folder is tracked... the "ignore" file won't work.

Comment: sorry @VonC, it didn't work, `$ git check-ignore -v -- ./.idea/vcs.xml` return nothing.
I had added `.idea` to my .gitignore_global.

Comment: if I add `.idea` to my local .gitignore, it works; but .gitignore_global, no.  I am pretty sure my .gitignore_global is functioning: i can create any folder and add the folder name to to .gitignore_glogbal, git will ignore it, with the exception of `.idea`.

Comment: @apollo Can you check your settings? It is called: "`core.excludesFile`" (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreexcludesFile). Not `core.excludefiles` for example: there could be a typo.

Comment: @apollo And can you add another file (outside `.idea`) to your `.gitignore_global` file? Just to see if that one is ignored?

Comment: @apollo Finally, can you set `core.excludesfile` to an absolute path, instead of `~/xxx`? As in `/home/yyy/xxx`

Comment: yes, is core.excludesFile (no 's'), yes, a folder specified in .gitignore_global is ignored, as long as it is not named .idea/. I have not tracked .idea (git add .idea/) in my project. I think jetbains must have configure git to 'force' it to not ignore .idea/.

Comment: @apollo And you did remove it from Git (`git rm --cached .idea/`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193807/discussion-between-apollo-and-vonc).